# AngularJS create a sign-out message for the next state only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

Here's the deal:
I am trying with to create a global alert message to notify a user he's done an action (for example, logged-out).

I am using [SB Admin 2.0 from StartAngular.com](http://start-angular.github.io/sb-admin-angular/preview/#/dashboard/home).
This is how it looks when I make a proper action.

[image: Global message]

Now, the question is actually, how would you do, that this message will last only state?
If I go let's us to '/login' state from here where I took the picture from (dashboard), the message will disappear.

I add a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/AmirTugi/4uasj5q4/1/).
Now it's not supposed to actually show the correct result, rather than give you the code I have currently.

The core is about me using a factory to hold some data I want to save between different states.
After I fill with the factory the data I want to insert in the message, I give the signal with a boolean.

Then, at the beginning of the controller* I seek that signal, and if it is on, I use [state change events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) to remove the log-out signal in the next state**.

```
$scope.userUtil = userUtil;

if ('loggedOut' in $scope.userUtil){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            console.log(1);
            delete $scope.userUtil.loggedOut;
        })
}
```

Do you think I am going in the right direction? Is there any way you see I can do it in a more simple way?

I appreciate your opinion.

*The controller is bound an ***abstract*** state called main (which includes the header, and sidebar)

**The method I am using currently is not perfect, it seems that the function I bind to the event is not a one timer. So if I log out once, I won't see the message again since every state I enter successfully, the log-out signal will be deleted no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, [this package](https://github.com/mateu-aguilo-bosch/message-center) does exactly what I need.